# How to prevent Liferay's <aui:form> form submission with Javascript?

Tags: java, jsp, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-7

I have a quite legacy project where we use some Java based portal/engine called **Liferay.**

In one of the `.jsp` files, I have this form *(logic and non-relevant code is missing, but form, submission logic and handler is present)*:

```
<aui:form action="/someURL" method="post" name="fm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <aui:fieldset >
        //Some code..
        <aui:button onClick="someJSandLiferayMethod();" type="submit" value='someNameHere' />
    </aui:fieldset>
</aui:form>
```

Also, in the same `.jsp` file, I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    AUI().use(
        'aui-tooltip', 'aui-base', 'selector-css3',
        function (A) {
            var form = A.one('#<portlet:namespace />fm');

            if (form) {
                form.on(
                    'submit',
                    function(event) {
                        //Some code here.. where validationErrors is either getting an object or not.
                        //Ultimate aim is to check validationErrors and depending on whether it has something or not, act accordingly. Namely:
                        //Do NOT submit the form if there are errors, and do otherwise.

                        if (validationErrors) {
                            event.halt();
                            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
        });
</script>
```

As you see in the comments, idea is that not to submit the form, when `validationErrors` are present. However, this does not work.

Please, before simply redirecting me some other so question, bear in mind, that I have seen most of them. Yes, they have some answers probably for those who knows this particular domain - **Liferay**. But for me, it's a bit tricky..

I purposefully omitted all the boilerplate here and left only the code which is attributable to the problem.

Maybe you can give me a clear idea and suggestion how to solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: It's an old issue, I know. 
Try this: <aui:form  onSubmit='<%="event.preventDefault();mySave()" ..
instead of your onClick

Answer (score 0):

You can add  call submitForm method for submitting the form, if you refer below url
https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/7.1.x/modules/apps/login/login-web/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/login.jsp

There in script  you can refer "submitForm(form)"

```
    <aui:script sandbox="<%= true %>">
        var form = document.getElementById('<portlet:namespace /><%= formName %>');

        if (form) {
            form.addEventListener(
                'submit',
                function(event) {
                    <c:if test="<%= Validator.isNotNull(redirect) %>">
                        var redirect = form.querySelector('#<portlet:namespace />redirect');

                        if (redirect) {
                            var redirectVal = redirect.getAttribute('value');

                            redirect.setAttribute('value', redirectVal + window.location.hash);
                        }
                    </c:if>

                    **submitForm(form);**
                }
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the code is using aui:form can we assume it is also using aui:field tags?  Is so, is there a reason you can't use the built-in validation features?

They handle the details, as well as providing the UI to inform the users of the validation failures in a manner consistent with Liferay.

https://portal.liferay.dev/docs/6-2/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/t/using-alloyui-form-validation